# Vue prop initialization/mutating

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have following code:

```
export default class LayoutComponent extends Vue {  
    @Prop() whiteBg: boolean;   
    ...
}
```

but when I compile it I get:

> property 'whiteBg' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

So I try to fix it by:

```
export default class LayoutComponent extends Vue {  
    @Prop() whiteBg: boolean = true;    
    ...
}
```

But then in chrome console I get error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

and Layout "ignore" whiteBg value set in parent component which use it.

**Question**: What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code

```
export default class LayoutComponent extends Vue {  
    @Prop() whiteBg!: boolean;      
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the following

```js
export default class LayoutComponent extends Vue {
    @Prop({ default: true }) whiteBg: boolean;
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator